# Adding ports to sources.list

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have manually added the following source to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main
```

I have done this to get some packages for the `armhf` target (specifically speaking libssl-dev:armhf package). But when I do `apt-get update`, I see that the program fails to find a release file. Here is the log.

```
...
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main armhf Packages                                             
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/universe armhf Packages                                         
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main armhf Packages                                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/restricted armhf Packages                                                
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe armhf Packages                                                  
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/multiverse armhf Packages                                                
Err:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main armhf Packages                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/universe armhf Packages                                          
Err:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports/universe armhf Packages                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Err:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main armhf Packages                                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/universe armhf Packages                                         
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                         
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have looked into the ports folder here : http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/eoan/, and I can see a **Release** file there. What could be the problem? Here is the list of foreign architectures I have.

```
subin@linux:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
armhf
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want *apt* to find http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/eoan/, you need to change the URL in the line to just http://ports.ubuntu.com/. ie:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main
```

Comment: This has interestingly resolved the `does not have a Release file` problem. But still the IPs are not found, and the system fails to fetch packages from the armhf architecture.

Comment: When you follow [this HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO), where exactly do you gen an error?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. When I follow that HOWTO, I see that when I install a package using `aptitude install libconfig:armhf`, the system suggests a solution. But nothing is installed, even if I accept a solution suggested by apt.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

[Apt can't find packages on Ubuntu 20.04 arm64 (Raspberry Pi 4)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255707/apt-cant-find-packages-on-ubuntu-20-04-arm64-raspberry-pi-4/1372223#1372223)

Replace "arm64" with "armhf" when adding those lines.