# Ubuntu 20.04, unable to get updates using while sudo apt-get update failed to fetch

Tags: 20.04, package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager

I am trying to update my ubuntu 20.04 using cmd sudo apt-get update. But it's saying Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I have also tried copying new sources.list but am still unable to fix it. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt update` ? The URLs in your post are not correct,

Comment: @SorenA Fetched 228 kB in 19s (12.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.. It's this one

Comment: `archive.ubuntu.com` does not have arm64 packages, which is why you are getting the 404 errors. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255707 for an example of a correct, working 20.04 arm64 /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: The URLs refers to `arm64` architecture, but the repositories seems to support only Amd64 and  I386 ... not Arm64.